# Serializing a nested Joda DateTime with Jackson and spring-boot

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, jodatime

I have an API I'm writing using Jackson and Sprint Boot. This API returns an object (`PipelineDetailsResponse`) containing a Joda DateTime object, as well as a List of Objects (`List<CommitDetail>`) containing a DateTime object.

However when I call the API, I see the `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp` fields correctly serialized as a unix timestamp, but `CommitDetails`' `timestamp` field is not. Do I need to do something special?

```
http localhost:8080/pipelines/FastLane_testGetDetails_100 Authorization:"Bearer ${JWT_TOKEN}"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
// headers tri

{
    "approvalDetails": null,
    "author": null,
    "buildNumber": 100,
    "commitDetailList": [
        {
            "author": "dalvizu",
            "message": "Some changes",
            "sha1": "1234",
            "timestamp": {
                "iChronology": {
                    "iBase": {
                        "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4.0
                    }
                },
                "iMillis": 1487807156248.0
            }
        }
    ],
    "commitUrl": null,
    "deployUrl": null,
    "endTimestamp": 1487720756247,
    "serviceName": "testGetDetails",
    "startTimestamp": 1487717156247,
    "uniqueId": "FastLane_testGetDetails_100"
}
```

In pom.xml I have added the jackson-datatype-joda jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

The object I am returning:

```
public class PipelineDetailsResponse
{

    private String uniqueId;
    private String deployUrl;
    private String commitUrl;
    private String serviceName;

    private List<CommitDetail> commitDetailList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String approvalDetails;
    private String author;
    private int buildNumber;

    private DateTime startTimestamp;
    private DateTime endTimestamp;
```

This references a list of CommitDetail which also contains a DateTime field:

```
public class CommitDetail
{
    private String author;

    private String sha1;

    private String message;

    private DateTime timestamp;
```

Here is the API method in my @RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pipelines/{uniqueId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable String uniqueId)
{
    PipelineDetailsResponse response = service.getPipelineDetails(uniqueId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `commitDetail` response has an object structure with different attributes but not a DateTime value. Which attribute value are you trying to retrieve from the timestamp object?

Comment: I would like my response to contain consistent JSON return values in `PipelineDetailsResponse.startTimeStamp` and `PipelineDetailsResponse.commitDetailsList.get(0).timestamp` - they are the same joda DateTime type. Ideally a unix timestamp value.

Comment: can you share the code that's setting the timestamp?

Comment: D'oh - I'm an idiot. I was saving the List<CommitDetail> in cassandra as JSON, but not saving it with Jackson

Comment: should I take it that you solved the issue?

Comment: yup problem solved